# using SQLite in lieu of Storage/Local storage Ionic 4 Native

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

Let's say I want to store chat messages locally in a Ionic 4 application but I don't want to delete and insert every `n` seconds can I use a separate SQLite file and just make sure that I sanitize the entries and be ok with that?

Right, so for security reasons and other aspects I am writing a chat application and have concluded the best thing to do would be to have a SQLite file where all messages could be stored. Now I hear you already, probably before you got to this part say "Hey!! Ionic 4 and Cordova already have a plug in for that!! AND it is based on SQLite!!" You would be correct, however, it is stored as a key/value pair and does not allow for any type of queries or table joins. the following methods are available(get, set, length, delete, forEach). What I would love is a simple update(). The only thing that I can see here would be a noSQL approach where updating is just deleting and reinserting.

Here is an example of what would be stored:

```
{
  conversations: [
    {id: 1, 
      people: ["Christian", "Sara"], 
      messages: [
        {id: 1, author: "Christian" content: "hi",  date: <date>},
        {id: 2, author: "Sara",     content: "foo", date: <date>}, 
        {id: 3 ...}
      ]
    },
    {id: 2, person: "Laura", messages: [{}, {}, {}]
  ]
}
```

So essentially what I would like to do is a `INSERT INTO messages WHERE id = :id` or something similar, instead of something like:

```
function update(){
  const oldMessages = this.storage.forEach('messages')
    .then(chat => {
      //loop over the chat and store each chat object in the old array,
    } 
 // set an interval that will retrieve the new messages 
//and append them into the old messages, then finally delete the old key/value storage and then
db.set('messagesChristianAndSara', messageArrayOfObjects)
}
```

This is a situation I think I will find myself in. Where I would rather just want to either push the object in or insert.

Maybe there is a way, but the docs aren't that clear about it.

Comment: Short answer yes you can

Comment: Long answer, in this case you are making a chat so you have a service to establish the comnuications through devices then you migth store the messages in that server or any one server and consume it when the chat is re opened

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I have socket.io as the actual relay and redis as a broker. So this is the ideal work flow:
1. user gets new message alert
2. opens up chat
3. redis delivers message to front end
4 front end receives message, inserts it into SQLite
4. delete message from redis

Comment: Why not save the messages and conversations as separate entries with their ids as the key? Updating would still mean replacing entries but a lot more granularly and searching would be easier.

Comment: @wcjord that's another option, but then when I want to load all the messages I would need to make sure that I prepend any chat with flag like "chat-user12345". But I think that it would be easier to search with something like: `this.storage.conversations.groupChats.forEach()`